# Ubuntu 14.04 running slow

Tags: 14.04

I have a HP workstation XW 4000, that previously ran Windows XP, I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04. it now lags and the screen glitches. The machines processor is an Intel Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.53GHz with 38.7 GB. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add more hardware information? you can `sudo apt-get install hwinfo` then run `hwinfo –short`. Provide this information along with whether you installed 64bit or 32bit 14.04

Comment: There is a other possibility, run in a Termninal `sudo lshw -html > ~/system.html` (hwinfo didn't worked for). After that you will find the file "system.html" with all necessary details in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Is your videocard driver up-to-date? If no, update it with the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-video-all libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
```

Are you running a 32 bit or 64 bit system, how much RAM does the system have?